# How to make child height 100% of container for different level of zoom

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to figure out how to make child height fill the container.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x16n2h8h/)

There 2 containers in my code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="blueBox"></div>
    <div class="redBox"></div>
    <div class="greenBox"></div>    
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="blueBox"></div>
    <div class="redBox"></div>
    <div class="greenBox"></div>        
</div>
```

**Case number 1: zoom 100%**

the first container has 'white space' before border-bottom, but the second container doesn't have one

[image]
**Case number 2: zoom 110%**

the second container has 'white space' before border-bottom, but the second container doesn't have one
[image]

**Case 3: zoom 125%**
both of containers don't have white space before border-bottom

[image]
**Question: why same code has different outputs? and how to remove the 'white space'**

Note: I'm using chrome 58.0.3029.110

Comment: Can you add images? I can't see the problem.

Comment: @ItayGanor added